# How to use Particle start color in unity3d 2017

Tags: unity, particles

I want to create a particle(prefab) and use another object color to change those particle's color but it seems everything is changed and I don't know the new method to use it.

Here my code:

```
 GameObject breakpart = Instantiate (smoke, gameObject.transform.position , Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;     

 breakpart.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
```

So how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particle Systems in Unity have modules to keep various bits of related data together. The start color is in the [Main module](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-main.html).

Set the [`startColor` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule-startColor.html):

```
var ps = breakpart.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
var main = ps.main;
main.startColor = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
```